# How to put protection on a word document, and the document was not distorted by means php?

Tags: php, doc, phpword

I found in Google a way to set a password  php using , but my background is distorted, the text is shifting, tell me what's the problem ?, I thought in the version of the Word I save to, but how to change it?
code :

```
$name = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
$name="sample";
$source = __DIR__ . "/{$name}.docx";

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);

// Add Password Protection For editing 
$documentProtection = $phpWord->getSettings()->getDocumentProtection();
$documentProtection->setEditing(PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\DocProtect::READ_ONLY);
$documentProtection->setPassword('123456');

// Write the output file

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

I tried to google, but paid libraries are not suitable, I tried to change the version of the Word in the save, but it does not change :(